# Flyway: Oracle create user conflicts with another user though user does not exist in the first place

Tags: oracle, flyway

Flyway 7.7.3

I created a couple of repeatable migrations sql like below:

R__create_role.sql

```
 -- Create role                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 CREATE ROLE ${roleName};                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
 -- Grant privileges to role                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 GRANT SELECT ON ${tableName} TO ${roleName};
```

R__create_user.sql

```
  -- Create user                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  CREATE USER ${newUser} IDENTIFIED BY ${userPwd};                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  -- Grant role to user                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  GRANT ${roleName} to ${newUser};
```

When I run flyway...migrate on this with supplied new user, I get below

```
CREATE USER TEST_USER_3 IDENTIFIED BY test3, Error Msg = ORA-01920: user name 'TEST_USER_3' 
conflicts with another user or role name
```

BUT, the new user is created anyway.

NOTE1: I did make sure that TEST_USER_3 is not in the database before I run flyway...migrate. Also, I tried adding `WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE;` after `CREATE USER ${newUser} IDENTIFIED BY ${userPwd};` (because i know it creates the new user anyway), but I still get the error message.

NOTE2: I did the same thing in postgres (repeatable migrations for create role and user) and it works just fine.

Is there something wrong with the way I set up the queries ? or is this an issue with flyway-oracle? and is there a solution to this ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have no role with such name?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, but I just realized that it has something to do with the fact that oracle user is pretty much the same as schema. So, when I pass the ${flyway:schemas} parameter, it creates a new user and then my sql query also creates a new user. So, I changed `Create new user ...` to `alter new user...` and that solved it :)